# Wordpress wp_mail not working on a few pages

Tags: email

My code:

```
 if(isset($_GET['order_success']) && $_GET['order_success'] == 1){
    $invoice_id = $_GET['invoice_id'];
    
    $to = $your_email;
    $subject = 'Payment Success';
    $body = 'Thank you for purchasing our service! Your invoice ID is: '.$invoice_id.'. We appreciate your business and hope you enjoy your purchase. If you have any questions or concerns, please don\'t hesitate to contact us. Best regards, Alzeen Rent A Car';
    
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: Your Name <contact@Example.com>',
    );
    
    $headers = wp_parse_args($headers);
    $mail = mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($body), $headers);
    
    if ($mail) {
        echo '<span class="payment_success">Payment Success. Check your email for confirmation OR Save Invoice ID:<code>'.$_GET['invoice_id'].'</code>.</span>';
    } else {
        echo 'An error occurred. Email not sent.';
    }

        
  }
```

It returns success but email is not receiving to me although I have installed the email logs plugin there too showing that the email is sent But not received.

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you looked at using `wp_mail` instead of `mail`? Unless you have an SMTP/dedicated email service there's a high chance emails sent this way will be discarded by email servers for anti-spam and security reasons, especially from shared hosting. If this is mission critical, you cannot rely on the native server email sending for it

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes I added wp_mail function but stll not working. Other web form are working fine. Only this causes an issue